# querySelect by the part of the css class

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible with js select specific elements that don't contain a specific part of the class like for example:

```
// This line seems to be an invalid query parameter, so I am curious if it's actually feasible to achieve that?
const queryResult = document.querySelectorAll(`ul:not('.*__list')`);
```

```js
const queryResult = document.querySelectorAll(`ul`);
console.log(queryResult)
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <button>button</button>
  </ul>
  <ul class="abstractPrefix__list">
    <li>
      <button class="abstractPrefix__button">button</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that the `class` attribute always ends with `__list`, then you can use the attribute selector `[class$='__list']`.

```js
const queryResult = document.querySelectorAll(`ul:not([class$='__list'])`);
console.log(queryResult)
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <button>button</button>
  </ul>
  <ul class="abstractPrefix__list">
    <li>
      <button class="abstractPrefix__button">button</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, this selector **will fail** if your class list looks like this: `class="abstractPrefix__list my_random_class"`, since it will no longer match the CSS attribute selector stated above. In this case, you will need a JS-based solution:

```js
const queryResult = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('ul')).filter(el => {
  const classes = Array.from(el.classList);
  for (let cl of classes) {
    if (cl.match(/__list$/gi)) {
      return false;
    }
    
    continue;
  }
  
  return true;
});
console.log(queryResult)
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <button>button</button>
  </ul>
  <ul class="abstractPrefix__list my_random_class">
    <li>
      <button class="abstractPrefix__button">button</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation:

https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#overview

Inside this page, read this:

> E[foo*="bar"]     an E element whose foo attribute value contains the
> substring bar
>
> E:not(s1, s2, …)  an E element that does not match either compound
> selector s1 or compound selector s2

So you have to use something similar to this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul:not([class*="__list"])')
```